# How to submit a form with a login button without jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this form which is in HTML

```
<form id="myform" action="handler.php">
   <input id="username" />
   <input id="password" type="password" />
   <button id="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

I would like to submit this form without using jquery, How do I do this?

also, I have the following code which needs to run before submit...

```
function validate(){
   return username.value && password.value;
}
```

Comment: <button type="submit" id="login">Login</button>

Comment: <form id="myform" action="handler.php" method = "post">

Comment: `jQuery` is just a library (or framework?) built on top of Javascript. Everything you can do with jQuery you can also do with pure javascript. Like `document.getElementById("myform").submit()` for example

Comment: Do you want it to be sent using ajax (without page reload) or as a simple HTML form?

Comment: In your validate you have `username` and `password` but they don't seem to be declared anywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing `<button id="login">Login</button>` by :

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

OR

```
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

And adding `onSubmit` event in your form like :

```
<form id="myform" action="handler.php" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

> be careful with your `validate()` function, where password and username needs to be set with `var password = document.getElementById("password");`

Answer (score 0):

**use type="submit"**

eg:

> `<button type="submit" id="login">Login</button>`